# Using NSIS Installer Name in various description Strings

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

So my NSIS script has the `Name` of installer as first line:

```
Name "Magic App"
```

Now for several pages (`COMPONENTS` page, `DIRECTORY` page, etc.), I have overridden the standard text as below:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Components to install"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "The following features of Magic App will be installed."
!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Click next to continue."
!define MUI_COMPONENTSPAGE_TEXT_COMPLIST "Components to install:"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS

!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_TEXT "Choose the folder where Magic App will be installed"
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Magic App files will be installed."
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Setup will install Magic App in the chosen folder. To install Magic App, click Browse and select a folder. Click Next to continue."
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
```

As clear from above, the name `Magic App` is getting repeated/used many times across all the description Strings. So if I change the name of the app in future, I need to make that change in all these places.

How can I reuse the `Name` of the installer in these description Strings ?

I tried using `${Name}`:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "The following features of ${Name} will be installed."
```

But its resulting in the following warning:

```
warning 6000: unknown variable/constant "{Name}" detected, ignoring (macro:MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT:10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${Name}` is syntax to access a define. You could create a define with that name of course but it is also possible to access the name **attribute** directly by using the langstring syntax:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "$(^Name) files will be installed."
```

Comment: For all referring this answer... please notice the difference between brackets in ${New} and $(^New).... do  not use ${^New} like I did.. :)

Comment: Yes, NSIS has {xx}, %xx%, (xx), (^xx) and no brackets.